# How to set all external links from a certain user to "nofollow"?

Tags: users, links, nofollow

I would like to know how I can set all external links in all posts from a certain wordpress user in my blog automatically to "nofollow" ? So that old postings and future postings from this user are affected by this "nofollow" command.
How is that possible?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You want to try something like this (untested):

```
// Nofollow in content
$author_id = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );
add_filter('the_content', 'my_nofollow');

function my_nofollow($content) {
    //return stripslashes(wp_rel_nofollow($content));

    return preg_replace_callback('/<a[^>]+/', 'my_nofollow_callback', $content);
}

function my_nofollow_callback($matches, $author_id) {
    $link = $matches[0];
    $site_link = get_bloginfo('url');
    if ($author_id === 4) {
        if (strpos($link, 'rel') === false) {
            $link = preg_replace("%(href=\S(?!$site_link))%i", 'rel="nofollow" $1', $link);
        } elseif (preg_match("%href=\S(?!$site_link)%i", $link) && (strpos($link, 'rel') === false)) {
            $link = preg_replace('/rel=\S(?!nofollow)\S*/i', 'rel="nofollow"', $link);
        }
    }
return $link;
}
```

Note: This is based on a nofollow function I am using on one of my sites and I just added a conditional for `if ( is_author () )` in there

Comment: Wow, nice! You have to know that I am a coding noob. So please can you tell me where I have to add this code? I guess in the function file? And: where you wrote the '4'  I have to write the authors name right? THX a bunch :)

Comment: Yes, you write the Author name in there or the Author ID. It goes in functions.php anywhere eg at the bottom. If there are any errors let me know.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. I tried the author id and the name but there is no nofollow in the authors postings.
if (is_author('4')) { AND if (is_author('AUTHORNAME')) { does not work

Comment: I've modified my answer. Where I've used 4 as the author, you need to change this to the actual ID of your author. The old version used `is_author` which is deprecated and also I shouldn't have put it inside apostrophes.